# How to make button in same line as input box that has dynamically added style

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap as my framework. I have an input box which is an autocomplete box that uses a jQuery plugin. I am trying to get a button next to it (inline-block) but it doesn't seem to work and is displayed below the autocomplete box.

I noticed that when the autocomplete plugin kicks in, it wraps the input box in a div so maybe that is the reason I can't get them in the same line.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
  <input id="autocomplete" type="text" value="" /> 
  <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" style="display:inline-block"> Search</button>
</div>
```

I have created a jsfiddle to reproduce my issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/rdawkins/Lh3fqy9w/15/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right, the issue is because your autocomplete gets wrapped in a `div`. So add `display:inline-block` to that `div` as well.

**CSS:**

```
.easy-autocomplete {  
    display:inline-block;    
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Lh3fqy9w/19/)**

Comment: Aha! It works now! Thank you so much, I appreciate it :)

Comment: @Bruno:your welcome :) . do accept the answer if this works for u.

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Microsmsm/Lh3fqy9w/22/)**

add `display:inline-block` to that div

```
.easy-autocomplete {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try floating the elements like this?

```
<div class="pull-left">
  <input type="text" value="" /> 
  <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Search</button>
</div>
```

It should work together with the column classes as well :)

Answer (score 0):

EasyComplete only wraps the input element. Try adding the recommended wrapper around both.

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
  <div class="autocomplete-wrap">
    <input id="autocomplete" type="text" value="" /> 
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm"> Search</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The extra `div` is ugly, but in my experience, making changes to the `div` that defines your columns often results in problems later.